# .htaccess mod_rewrite with various URL depth

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess mod_rewrite with various URL depth

I am new to mod_rewrite and trying to make a single mode_rewrite command to cover all possible URL depths and show the index page.

The max of length:

```
loader.php?lang=en&cat0=products&cat1=books&cat2=cooking&pageid=pudding
/en/products/books/cooking/pudding.php

loader.php?lang=en&cat0=products&pageid=index
/en/products/index.php
```

The URLs always start with 'lang' and ends with the 'pageid' but the depth in the middle can vary.

Comment: Better: write multiple rules -- much safer and easier to implement.

Comment: If you're smart about it, you can do it in two rules. Hint: One rule to gather the `cat0`, `cat1`, `cat2`, etc. with the `[N]` flag (be very careful here), and the second rule to rewrite to the `pageid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?/([^/]+)\.php loader.php?lang=$1&cat0=$2&cat1=$3&cat2=$4&pageid=$5 [L]
```

if I'm correct.

Comment: PS why do you want your urls to end with `.php`? It has no function and is kind of ugly.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it at the moment .php is not my concern. about the above code I think we need to make exception for /images or /css or /js folders as they will get caught by the above .htaccess or may be hardcode /products in to htaccess?

Comment: Just put the following above it `RewriteRule ^(images|css|js)/ - [L]`